# Are locally compact, Hausdorff, locally path-connected topological groups locally Euclidean?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Is every locally compact, Hausdorff, locally path-connected topological group $G$ locally Euclidean? (That would imply of course also being a Lie group.) Is it true when countable basis is assumed? I wasn't able to find a discussion of this question in the literature on topological groups and the Hilbert 5th problem.

EDIT: As YCor rightly [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385829/are-locally-compact-hausdorff-locally-path-connected-topological-groups-locall#comment983279_385829), let's assume that $G$ is of finite topological dimension. The general theme of my question is to identify a minimal set of conditions on a topological group making it into a Lie group.

Comment: You probably want finite-dimensional, or something. Otherwise, any infinite product of positive-dimensional compact connected Lie groups will provide a counterexample. For instance, infinite-dimensional tori $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^X$, $X$ infinite, satisfy the assumption (for $X$ countable this is second countable).

Comment: If you browse Annals of Math in the years 1940-1955 you find a considerable literature on  the subject.

Comment: Actually, even more is true and every locally compact finite dimensional group is locally a topological product of Cantor set and $R^n$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's an interesting fact. Would you know a reference to it?

Comment: In the case of compact (Hausdorff) groups, this is due to Pontryagin, see the reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567423/finite-dimensional-group-is-locally-a-manifold-or-product-with-a-cantor-set/3567475#3567475). The general case follows from the approximation property (of l.c. groups by Lie groups). I will write a proof when I have more time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under the additional assumption of finite topological dimension pointed by YCor in the comments to the OP, the answer is *yes*, see e.g. Theorem 10, pp. 120 of the paper of K. Whittington, *Local connectedness in topological groups*, [Topology and its Applications **180** (2015) 111-123](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2014.11.006). In fact, according to the same Theorem the hypothesis of local compactness is not needed and follows from the others. The second axiom of countability is also not needed.

**Edit:** in due time, the hypotheses needed for a positive solution to Hilbert's 5th problem when the assumption of finite topological dimension is allowed to fail were a major theme in Per Enflo's PhD thesis (1970).

**Edit 2:** Implication (2) $\Rightarrow$ (3) of Theorem 10 *ibid.* is a literal citation of Theorem 4.10.1, page 185 of the book by D. Montgomery and L. Zippin, *Topological Transformation Groups* (Wiley Interscience, 1955), see Theorem 2 in Moishe Kohan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addendum to Pedro's answer:

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $G$ is a locally compact finite dimensional (Hausdorff) topological group. Then $G$ is locally homeomorphic to the product of a totally disconnected space and ${\mathbb R}^n$.

A reference for this result (that should be better known) is

*Montgomery, Deane; Zippin, Leo*, Topological transformation groups, Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 978-0-486-82449-9). xi, 289 p. (2018). [ZBL1418.57024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1418.57024).

section 4.9.3. (The actual theorem says a bit more, namely that locally, at $e$, $G$ is a product of a local Lie group and a totally disconnected group.

In the same book you will also find Theorem 4.10.1 answering your original question:

**Theorem 2.** If $G$ is a locally compact, locally connected and finite dimensional topological group, then $G$ is a Lie group (possibly non-2nd countable).

Of course, this is a consequence of Theorem 1.

Comment: Granted that the proof of Whittington's Theorem 10 uses Theorem 4.10.1 from Montgomery-Zippin (the latter is the former's implication (2) => (3)). However, the former is stronger in the sense that local compactness needs not to be assumed and is rather a consequence.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro I would have to read Whittington's paper to understand what these parts are.

Comment: Did you forget to assume finite dimension in Theorem 1?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Yes, I did. Thanks!